# Select2 (multiple selection) - how to display alternative placeholder if at least one element has been selected already?

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, jquery-select2

I have [select2 example](http://jsfiddle.net/sveller/uWJDd/5/) which looks like this:

```
<select 
    multiple="true"
    placeholder='Select something'
    allowClear: false
    data-bind="
        options: states, 
        optionsValue: 'id', 
        optionsText: 'text', 
        selectedOptions: selectMultipleStates, 
        select2: {}"
    style="width: 500px"
</select>
```

I would like to have **two** placeholders:

- the usual one (*select something*) shown when there is no selection at all
- another one (*select more*) which will be shown if at least one element is selected
  already

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing that would be to have two select tag in your html, and make the second one hidden when your page load, then add an onchange attribute on the first one and run a function that will show the second select tag wih it's first choice being select more. It would give you something like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <SCRIPT>
  window.onload=function(){
             document.getElementById('mysecondselecttag').style.display = "none";
                         };
  function ShowOtherTag()
   {
    document.getElementById('mysecondselecttag').style.display = "block";
   }
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <select id="myfirstselectag" onchange="ShowOtherTag()">
  <option value="0">Select something</option>   
  <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
  <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
  <option value="3">Choice 3</option>     
 </select>
 <select id="mysecondselecttag">
  <option value="0">Select more</option>    
  <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
  <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
  <option value="3">Choice 3</option>     
 </select>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work; so far I couldn't make select2 to show placeholder if there is a selection already ...

Comment: well the code I've shown you does something like you need at least I think, unless I haven't understood what you need to do.

Comment: *the code I've shown you does something like you need* - sorry, but it does not. For example, second select would not show "select more" if any items from that second select are chosen already